# NullPointerException from spinner.setAdapter()

Tags: java, android, spinner

I want to create a spinner to show the list `m`. But the following code gives `NullPointerException` at `spinner.setAdapter(spinner_adapter)`. Why does this happen?

```
public class Request extends ListActivity {
    private static final String[] m={"A","B","O","AB","others"};   
    private TextView view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(),
            R.layout.listitem, new String[] { "name", "quant" },
            new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.quant });
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);  
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);  
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,m);  
        spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
        spinner.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);              
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerSelectedListener());  
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    }

    class SpinnerSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{              
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,  
            long arg3) {  
            view.setText(""+m[arg2]);  
        }  
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {       
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling `setContentView` before accessing views from layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
```

ends up the `spinner` being null, since no content view has been assigned to your activity.

Thus, when trying to interact with your spinner, a NPE is thrown.

Add the `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_content);` to the onCreate method, before initializing its views.

Comment: Thanks, but as this activity is extended from ListActivity, when I do setContentView(R.layout.main); The error is "your content must have a listview whose id is attribute is 'android.R.id.list'". How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: well, add a ```ListView``` to your main layout then with ```android:id="@+android:id/list"```. It's important to have the id point to ```the android.R.list``` id, that's what the ```ListView``` implementation is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are trying to use `IDs` from layout and you missed to call `setContentView`. Call it just below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
setContentView(<YourLayout>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing those views in your onCreate i.e

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
```

The id is present in **R.java** file, cause you have proper layout , But for accessing those will fails causing **nullpointer** at **runtime** to all of your views

You Need to add

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

inside **onCreate** where main is your layout i.e **main.xml** which contains **spinner01**

Comment: Thanks, but as this activity is extended from ListActivity, when I do setContentView(R.layout.main); The error is "your content must have a listview whose id is attribute is 'android.R.id.list'". How to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `ListView` Default layout both `TextView` and `Spinner` will be null cause there are no `R.id.spinnerText` nor `R.id.spinner01`

So you should implement your custom layout

```
setContentView(...);
```

in this layout there should be

**`ListView`** with an id of `@android:id/list`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**`Spinner`** with an id of `@+id/spinner01`

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**`TextView`** with an id of `@+id/spinnerText`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```